# Requests 2.0, empty data in graph after successfully sending requests

Tags: facebook, apprequests

I'm seeing some strange behaviour with Requests.

I initiate a requests dialog with:

```
method: 'apprequests'
to: 'someUid'
```

(and some data for message, title, data)

The user approves the Request, and I get back a valid response, giving me the request Id, the user Ids it was sent to, and the updatedFrictionless flag. However, when reading the request from the graph later with either:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=REQUESTID_USERID&access_token=RECEIVINGUSERTOKEN
or
https://graph.facebook.com/REQUESTID_USERID?access_token=RECEIVINGUSERTOKEN
```

I get back no data !

The first graph call will give me an empty array (an un-named array not 'data', just simply [ ] )
The second, gives me 'false'

REQUESTID is the request Id I get back from the original call, USERID is the receiving USERID.

The receiving user is me, and **I do see the request in my notifications, but using the graph explorer to check my 'apprequests', its empty.**

Any ideas? I have Requests 2.0 enabled, and call FB.init with frictionlessRequests: true..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it work with your app access token?

Comment: just to add docs are little misleading on this, they actually specify USER_ACCESS_TOKEN in the examples for reading requests. Also, this means we can't delete/clear/otherwise manipulate requests from the client side, a minor inconvenience, but the docs show examples of deleting requests using the Js SDK.

Comment: It actually sounds like a bug; as far as I'm aware a user access token generated by an app should be able to see and delete requests sent to that user by that app - my answer was more a 'try this and see if it works' than 'you're doing it wrong'

Comment: oh ehmm, this is dumb, I was using the the wrong access token! /apprequests will always be empty in the graph explorer as its app specific, requests are hidden when not using a token from the app who made them. obvious now..! delete method actually gives a 'Entity is not visible' error.